Compiling GDB on Windows using msys2 in 2024
Seen multiple existing posts, but not able to solve the compile time errors in GDB using MSYS2.
I am using the MINGW64 console. Compiled the missing dependencies GMP and MPFR on same setup sucessfully.
The GDB compilation on same Windows system is failing with errors in libiberty module.
The command used is : ./configure --prefix=/devdash/install/ --with-gmp=/devdash/install --with-mpfr=/devdash/install --enable-static --disable-shared --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
The errors :
make[1]: Entering directory '/devdash/binutils-gdb'
make[2]: Entering directory '/devdash/binutils-gdb/libiberty'
if [ x"" != x ]; then \
  gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2      -I. -I./../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow=local -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE   ./pex-win32.c -o pic/pex-win32.o; \
else true; fi
if [ x"" != x ]; then \
  gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2      -I. -I./../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow=local -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE    ./pex-win32.c -o noasan/pex-win32.o; \
else true; fi
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2      -I. -I./../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow=local -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE  ./pex-win32.c -o pex-win32.o
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_open_read’:
./pex-win32.c:122:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_open’; did you mean ‘open’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  122 |   return _open (name, _O_RDONLY | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT));
      |          ^~~~~
      |          open
./pex-win32.c:122:23: error: ‘_O_RDONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_RDONLY’?
  122 |   return _open (name, _O_RDONLY | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT));
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
      |                       O_RDONLY
./pex-win32.c:122:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
./pex-win32.c:122:45: error: ‘_O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_BINARY’?
  122 |   return _open (name, _O_RDONLY | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT));
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                             O_BINARY
./pex-win32.c:122:57: error: ‘_O_TEXT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_TEXT’?
  122 |   return _open (name, _O_RDONLY | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT));
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~
      |                                                         O_TEXT
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_open_write’:
./pex-win32.c:136:18: error: ‘_O_WRONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_WRONLY’?
  136 |                 (_O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
      |                  O_WRONLY
./pex-win32.c:136:30: error: ‘_O_CREAT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_CREAT’?
  136 |                 (_O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
      |                              O_CREAT
./pex-win32.c:136:41: error: ‘_O_TRUNC’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_TRUNC’?
  136 |                 (_O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~
      |                                         O_TRUNC
./pex-win32.c:137:30: error: ‘_O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_BINARY’?
  137 |                  | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT)),
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~
      |                              O_BINARY
./pex-win32.c:137:42: error: ‘_O_TEXT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_TEXT’?
  137 |                  | (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT)),
      |                                          ^~~~~~~
      |                                          O_TEXT
./pex-win32.c:138:17: error: ‘_S_IREAD’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘S_IREAD’?
  138 |                 _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                 S_IREAD
./pex-win32.c:138:28: error: ‘_S_IWRITE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘S_IWRITE’?
  138 |                 _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
      |                            S_IWRITE
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_close’:
./pex-win32.c:146:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_close’; did you mean ‘close’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  146 |   return _close (fd);
      |          ^~~~~~
      |          close
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘win32_spawn’:
./pex-win32.c:670:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  670 |       pid = (pid_t) pi->hProcess;
      |             ^
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘spawn_script’:
./pex-win32.c:695:31: error: ‘_O_RDONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_RDONLY’?
  695 |   int fd = _open (executable, _O_RDONLY);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~
      |                               O_RDONLY
./pex-win32.c:702:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_read’; did you mean ‘read’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  702 |       int len = _read (fd, buf, sizeof (buf) - 1);
      |                 ^~~~~
      |                 read
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_exec_child’:
./pex-win32.c:800:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_dup’; did you mean ‘dup’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  800 |   in = _dup (orig_in);
      |        ^~~~
      |        dup
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_wait’:
./pex-win32.c:932:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  932 |   h = (HANDLE) pid;
      |       ^
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_pipe’:
./pex-win32.c:964:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_pipe’; did you mean ‘pipe’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  964 |   return _pipe (p, 256, (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT) | _O_NOINHERIT);
      |          ^~~~~
      |          pipe
./pex-win32.c:964:35: error: ‘_O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_BINARY’?
  964 |   return _pipe (p, 256, (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT) | _O_NOINHERIT);
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                   O_BINARY
./pex-win32.c:964:47: error: ‘_O_TEXT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘O_TEXT’?
  964 |   return _pipe (p, 256, (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT) | _O_NOINHERIT);
      |                                               ^~~~~~~
      |                                               O_TEXT
./pex-win32.c:964:58: error: ‘_O_NOINHERIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  964 |   return _pipe (p, 256, (binary ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT) | _O_NOINHERIT);
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./pex-win32.c:965:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  965 | }
      | ^
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_open_write’:
./pex-win32.c:139:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  139 | }
      | ^
./pex-win32.c: In function ‘pex_win32_open_read’:
./pex-win32.c:123:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  123 | }
      | ^
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1174: pex-win32.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/devdash/binutils-gdb/libiberty'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9555: all-libiberty] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/devdash/binutils-gdb'
make: *** [Makefile:1041: all] Error 2


I'd look into how MSYS2 developers build it. They should have a PKGBUILD script for it.

@HolyBlackCat I will attempt with the configure options in the said file : https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-gdb/PKGBUILD

What version of gdb are attempting to build?

What gcc do you use? Try gcc -dumpmachine.

Why not just install it through msys2/pacman?

Are you building it in the correct MSYS2 environment?

In the PKGBUILD there is a hack at the bottom of the prepare() function related to libiberty.

That hack looks weird, how does adding -O2 fix something?

@ssbssa MINGW64 ~ # gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-pc-msys

That's what I thought, x86_64-pc-msys produces executables for msys2 itself, not 'real' native windows ones. You probably need to install mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc.

I finally moved to Cygwin, installed packages of Devel category and compiled gbd.exe successfully from the source. Compiled GMP and MPFR too, as both were missing !! . Will test the gdb.exe next.
